# Problems in Eclipse when trying to merge branch with trunk using Subversive

Tags: java, svn, merge, subversive

I've got a problem when trying to merge my branch with my trunk . That is I want to copy what I have worked with in my branch to my trunk. This is what I did:

Switched to trunk,

Right clicked on project

team > merge

Gave the URL to the branch

Clicked OK

Then I get this view in eclipse where it shows some conflicts. The conflicts are represented by a <> symbol in red. And after my src folder and test folder it says "unversioned".

I don't understand this what have I done wrong? I comitted everything inside my src folder and test folder before trying to merge, but now it says my src folder and test folder has not been merged?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Subclipse, but I would think it behaves in the same was as Subversive. When merging two branches, some code conflicts can't be automatically resolved, and you need to do this manually by editing the file and reviewing what's changed. Once this is done, then you can mark the conflict as resolved.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to compare at all. But i found another solution just to merge source folder with source folder and test folder with test folder, as nothing else changes, I presume. Seems to work